# Python object attribute can't be reached by assignment

Tags: python, class, object, methods

I have the following method definition in my class:

```
def show_values(self):
        for node in self.Nodes:
            nod = self.Nodes[node]
            print self.M.nod.value
```

I receive the following error

```
File "nfg.py", line 30, in show_values
    print self.M.nod.value
AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'nod'
```

I want to reach to `self.M.(self.Nodes[node]).value`, of course, but do not know
how. Can you help me?

Comment: Do you mean `self.M[nod].value` ? What is `M`, anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `self.Nodes[node]` is a string that you want to use for an attribute lookup, try the following:

```
def show_values(self):
    for node in self.Nodes:
        nod = self.Nodes[node]
        print getattr(self.M, nod).value
```

Note that `getattr(foo, 'bar')` is equivalent to `foo.bar`.

If `self.M` is a dictionary or other mapping type and you want to do a key lookup, use the following:

```
def show_values(self):
    for node in self.Nodes:
        nod = self.Nodes[node]
        print self.M[nod].value
```

Answer (score 1):

What is `M`? If `nod` (i.e., `self.nodes[node]`) is a string containing the name of an attribute of `self.M`, you can access that attribute via `M`'s namespace dictionary, `self.M.__dict__`. So to access its `value` field, use `self.M.__dict__[nod].value`.

If that's not what you're trying to do, I suggest you provide a little more information about your class.

Answer (score 0):

you are saying:

```
print self.M.nod.value
```

use this instead:

```
print self.M.node.value
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP wanted to use `nod` in fact, to retrieve `M`'s attribute or hash element, which is unclear.